# Future with asynchronous resolve does not fire

Tags: swift, combine

I am currently trying to learn Swift+Combine, but I even fail at replicating a simple tutorial.

My current playground project looks as follows:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

let future = Future<Int, Never> { promise in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        print("hello")
        promise(.success(1))
    }
}

future.sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
            receiveValue: { print($0) })

print("end")

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    print(future)
}
```

I would have expected as output:

```
end
hello
1
finished
Combine.Future<Swift.Int, Swift.Never>
```

But when I run this code, the output only displays:

```
end
hello
Combine.Future<Swift.Int, Swift.Never>
```

It seems to swallow the whole sink. At first I thought maybe the future was already deleted by the time the DispatchQueue fired its callback, but this does not seem to be the case.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the subscription you create with `sink`, otherwise the subscription and hence the subscriber gets deallocated straight away and hence there won't be any values emitted from `Future`, the `Publisher`.

```
let futureSubscription = future.sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
        receiveValue: { print($0) })
```